# Regular expression without "Double or more" spaces

Tags: html, regular-language

I need a regular expression that allows:

1. You cannot put a space at the beginning and end of a line
2. There can only be one space between words

I had enough for something like "^[АЯ-Ёа-яё0-9' ']+$", - but that's not what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
^(?! )(?!.*  )(?!.* $)[^\s].*$
```

Here's a breakdown of the expression:

- ^: Asserts the start of the line.
- (?! ): Negative lookahead to disallow a space at the beginning of the line.
- (?!.* ): Negative lookahead to disallow two or more consecutive spaces within the string.
- (?!.* $): Negative lookahead to disallow a space at the end of the line.
- [^\s]: Match any non-whitespace character.
- .*: Match any character (except a newline) 0 or more times.
- $: Asserts the end of the line.

I have put together a mini test on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/ko3Mq3/2).

Comment: It works, thanks for recommending the site!